# converting Tensorflow Object Detection API (ssdlite_mobilenet_v3_small) to openvino IR failure

Tags: tensorflow, openvino

I have trained my ssdlite_mobilenet_v3 in tensorflow and export as frozen_inference_graph.pb. I am able to run it. Now I would like to convert to openvino Inference Engine files (.xml and .bin). But I encounter following errors. I include my command line below and also you may download my model files in a [sample_model_inference.zip here](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/issues/569). Could anyone help me to find out what's missing? or how to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Command line:

```
mo_tf.py --input_model ../sample_model_inference/frozen_inference_graph.pb --transformations_config /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_v2_support.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ../sample_model_inference/pipeline.config
```

Error messages:

(openvino) paul@tensor:~/tf1.15/models/research/object_detection/samples/sample_model_ir$ mo_tf.py --input_model ../sample_model_inference/frozen_inference_graph.pb --transformations_config /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_v2_support.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ../sample_model_inference/pipeline.config
Model Optimizer arguments:
Common parameters:
    - Path to the Input Model:     /home/paul/tf1.15/models/research/object_detection/samples/sample_model_ir/../sample_model_inference/frozen_inference_graph.pb
    - Path for generated IR:     /home/paul/tf1.15/models/research/object_detection/samples/sample_model_ir/.
    - IR output name:     frozen_inference_graph
    - Log level:     ERROR
    - Batch:     Not specified, inherited from the model
    - Input layers:     Not specified, inherited from the model
    - Output layers:     Not specified, inherited from the model
    - Input shapes:     Not specified, inherited from the model
    - Mean values:     Not specified
    - Scale values:     Not specified
    - Scale factor:     Not specified
    - Precision of IR:     FP32
    - Enable fusing:     True
    - Enable grouped convolutions fusing:     True
    - Move mean values to preprocess section:     False
    - Reverse input channels:     False
TensorFlow specific parameters:
    - Input model in text protobuf format:     False
    - Path to model dump for TensorBoard:     None
    - List of shared libraries with TensorFlow custom layers implementation:     None
    - Update the configuration file with input/output node names:     None
    - Use configuration file used to generate the model with Object Detection API:     /home/paul/tf1.15/models/research/object_detection/samples/sample_model_ir/../sample_model_inference/pipeline.config
    - Operations to offload:     None
    - Patterns to offload:     None
    - Use the config file:     None
Model Optimizer version:     2020.1.0-61-gd349c3ba4a
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:493: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:494: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:495: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:496: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:497: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/paul/openvino/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:502: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
The Preprocessor block has been removed. Only nodes performing mean value subtraction and scaling (if applicable) are kept.
[ ERROR ]  Failed to match nodes from custom replacement description with id 'ObjectDetectionAPISSDPostprocessorReplacement':
It means model and custom replacement description are incompatible.
Try to correct custom replacement description according to documentation with respect to model node names
[ ERROR ]  Cannot infer shapes or values for node "Postprocessor/Cast_1".
[ ERROR ]  0
[ ERROR ]
[ ERROR ]  It can happen due to bug in custom shape infer function .
[ ERROR ]  Or because the node inputs have incorrect values/shapes.
[ ERROR ]  Or because input shapes are incorrect (embedded to the model or passed via --input_shape).
[ ERROR ]  Run Model Optimizer with --log_level=DEBUG for more information.
[ ANALYSIS INFO ]  Your model looks like TensorFlow Object Detection API Model.
Check if all parameters are specified:
    --tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config
    --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config
    --input_shape (optional)
    --reverse_input_channels (if you convert a model to use with the Inference Engine sample applications)
Detailed information about conversion of this model can be found at
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_tf_specific_Convert_Object_Detection_API_Models.html
[ ERROR ]  Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID" (): Stopped shape/value propagation at "Postprocessor/Cast_1" node.
 For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimizer_FAQ.html), question #38.

Comment: I am encountering the same issues. I will let you know if i succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use transformation config according to your tensorflow version
e.g. 1.14 or 1.15

For example

```
mo_tf.py --input_model ../sample_model_inference/frozen_inference_graph.pb --transformations_config /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_support_api_v1.14.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ../sample_model_inference/pipeline.config
```

OR

```
mo_tf.py --input_model ../sample_model_inference/frozen_inference_graph.pb --transformations_config /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_support_api_v1.15.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ../sample_model_inference/pipeline.config
```